# How to change date language without changing the entire site language?

Tags: php, plugin-development, multi-language

I want my entire site in English, but the dates to be in another language.

I tried to set PHP local like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he');
```

Setting my whole website to another language from the admin panel does change the time language, but I don't want this.
Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Where do you want to time to display in the new language? Only on the front-end, or in all admin screens as well?

Comment: Only in the front end of the site, Still didn't found the write way. Of course I can search for the English words and replace them with my lang manually but that is not optimal.

Comment: Don't forget about date_i18n https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a multilingual site; even if you aren't displaying multiple languages on the admin side, it sounds like you want one language in the backend and another on the frontend.

You might want to check out [WPBeginner's article on multi-language WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-easily-create-a-multilingual-wordpress-site/).

If *all* you are changing is the date language, and you are comfortable editing template, then you can [alter the date displays alone using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975854/translating-php-date-for-multilingual-site).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the global site language under Settings > General, but then edit your user account to set the admin language to whatever you want for your user account. For more info reference https://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-7-to-introduce-user-specific-language-setting-for-the-admin